# Localize plotly plot time axis for dates in R

Tags: r, localization, plotly

I would like to localize a plotly graph date axis date format for a special country. Instead of labeling dates in the time axis as "Jan 8   Jan 9  Jan 10...", I want to label them "Oca 8 Oca 9 Oca 10" in Turkish locale. The sample plotly code in R is given below. I know that I need to use `config(locale = "tr_TR")` to do this. But I am not sure how to do this in the code below.

````
  plotly::plot_ly() %>%
  plotly::add_trace(
    x = ~date,
    y = ~Belgium,
    type = "scatter",
    mode = "lines+markers",
    name = "Türkiye"
  ) %>%
  plotly::add_trace(
    x = ~date,
    y = ~France,
    type = "scatter",
    mode = "lines+markers",
    name = "Fransa"
  ) %>%
  plotly::add_trace(
    x = ~date,
    y = ~Spain,
    type = "scatter",
    mode = "lines+markers",
    name = "İspanya"
  ) %>%
  plotly::add_trace(
    x = ~date,
    y = ~Italy,
    type = "scatter",
    mode = "lines+markers",
    name = "Italya"
  ) %>%
  plotly::layout(
    title = "",
    legend = list(x = 0.1, y = 0.9),
    yaxis = list(title = "Toplam Onaylı Vakalar"),
    xaxis = list(title = "Date"),
    # paper_bgcolor = "black",
    # plot_bgcolor = "black",
    # font = list(color = 'white'),
    hovermode = "compare",
    margin = list(
      # l = 60,
      # r = 40,
      b = 10,
      t = 10,
      pad = 2
    )
  )```
````

Answer (score 1):

I just added the following

```
    )%>%
    plotly::config(
    locale='tr')
)
```

This configuration sets the date axis labeling based on system locale.